# How to sort text mixed number with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, underscore.js

I have some problem about sort value with _.sortBy(underscore.js).And
I have some value like this:

```
[
  {
    first: A,
    second: 10,
    third: D3
  }
  {
    first: B,
    second: 2,
    third: F3
  }
  {
    first: C,
    second: 3,
    third: G4
  }
  {
    first: A,
    second: 9,
    third: G5
  }
]
```

And I try to sort it with:

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(list_data, function(data) {
   return [data[0].first, data[0].second.join("_");
});
```

it's always return `[{first:A,second:10,third:D3}, {first:A,second:9,third:G6}, {first:B,second:2,third:F3}, {first:C,second:3,third:G4}]`

but i want it to return like this `[{first:A,second:9,third:G6}, {first:A,second:10,third:D3}, {first:B,second:2,third:F3}, {first:C,second:3,third:G4}]`

How can i do ? pleace help, I'm a newcomer for this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sortedArray = _(list_data)
                  .chain()
                  .sortBy(function(data){
                    return data.second;
                  })
                  .sortBy(function(data){
                    return data.first;
                  })
                  .value();
```

Comment: I'm already try your code in JS Bin and it work perfectly, But not sure for every object in my array. i will go back to check and if it's work i will accept your answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Array.prototype.sort https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
var array = [
  {
    first: 'C',
    second: 3,
    third: 'D3'
  },
  {
    first: 'A',
    second: 9,
    third: 'G5'
  }
];

var sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
   var first = a.first + a.second + a.third;
   var second = b.first + b.second + b.third;
   return first.localeCompare(second);
});
```

Comment: for your solution, It will check only second key. Ex: if i have {first:C, second: 3, third:A1}. the result will return {first:C, second: 3, third:A1},, {first: 'A',second: 9,third: 'G5' }, {first: 'A', second: 10, third: 'D3'}.So i don't want like that. i want to check key["first"] then check key["second"] and then check key["third"]

Comment: I add more object to array please check my edit question again.  @user874774

Comment: @thanapatsaeliu you just have to adapt your comparing function. See edit.